# Consuming a kinesis stream in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, stream, boto

I cant seem to find a decent example that shows how can I consume an AWS Kinesis stream via Python. Can someone please provide me with some examples I could look into?

Best

Comment: Will really appreciate some help on this guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While this question has already been answered, it might be a good idea for future readers to consider using the `Kinesis Client Library (KCL) for Python` instead of using `boto` directly.  It simplifies consuming from the stream *when you have multiple consumer instances, and/or changing shard configurations*.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/speak-to-kinesis-in-python/

A more [complete enumeration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html) of what the KCL provides

- Connects to the stream
- Enumerates the shards
- **Coordinates shard associations with other workers (if any)**
- Instantiates a record processor for every shard it manages
- Pulls data records from the stream
- Pushes the records to the corresponding record processor
- **Checkpoints processed records** *(it uses DynamoDB so your code doesn't have to manually persist the checkpoint value)*
- **Balances shard-worker associations when the worker instance count changes**
- **Balances shard-worker associations when shards are split or merged**

The items in bold are the ones that I think are where the KCL really provides non-trivial value over boto.  But depending on your usecase boto may be much much much simpler.

Comment: Where was this when I was suffering :(

Comment: Also, if you haven't used kinesis before, you may run into this. It's not directly related to the KCL, but the KCL helps make this scenario a little more mysterious. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863095/expected-behavior-for-aws-kinesis-sharditeratortype-trim-horizon

Comment: really dig my head into KCL, finding it is calling a daemon running in Java. This make my debugging and customizing my code really difficult in python. Boto gives me full control and I have to know how it work internally.

Comment: Using boto is definitely more straightforward, and it's clearer what's happening.  But using the KCL "automatically" takes care of some non-trivial tasks if you have a more complex deployment.  I'll update my original answer to point out some of those tasks.  I'm not pushing KCL over the use of boto, just explaining when/how the KCL might outweigh boto's simplicity.

Answer (score 39):

you should use boto.kinesis:

```
from boto import kinesis
```

After you created a stream:

step 1: connect to aws kinesis:

```
auth = {"aws_access_key_id":"id", "aws_secret_access_key":"key"}
connection = kinesis.connect_to_region('us-east-1',**auth)
```

step 2: get the stream info (like how many shards, if it is active ..)

```
tries = 0
while tries < 10:
    tries += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        response = connection.describe_stream('stream_name')   
        if response['StreamDescription']['StreamStatus'] == 'ACTIVE':
            break 
    except :
        logger.error('error while trying to describe kinesis stream : %s')
else:
    raise TimeoutError('Stream is still not active, aborting...')
```

step 3 : get all shard ids, and for each shared id get the shard iterator:

```
shard_ids = []
stream_name = None 
if response and 'StreamDescription' in response:
    stream_name = response['StreamDescription']['StreamName']                   
    for shard_id in response['StreamDescription']['Shards']:
         shard_id = shard_id['ShardId']
         shard_iterator = connection.get_shard_iterator(stream_name, shard_id, shard_iterator_type)
         shard_ids.append({'shard_id' : shard_id ,'shard_iterator' : shard_iterator['ShardIterator'] })
```

step 4 : read the data for each shard

limit is the limit of records that you want to receive. (you can receive up to 10 MB)
shard_iterator is the shared from previous step.

```
tries = 0
result = []
while tries < 100:
     tries += 1
     response = connection.get_records(shard_iterator = shard_iterator , limit = limit)
     shard_iterator = response['NextShardIterator']
     if len(response['Records'])> 0:
          for res in response['Records']: 
               result.append(res['Data'])                  
          return result , shard_iterator
```

in your next call to get_records, you should use the shard_iterator that you received with the result of the previous get_records.

**note**: in one call to get_records, (limit = None) you can receive empty records.
if calling to get_records with a limit, you will get the records that are in the same partition key (when you put data in to stream, you have to use partition key :

```
connection.put_record(stream_name, data, partition_key)
```

Comment: sure, hope it helps.. :)

Comment: some stuff are not working but (shared_id?) but thanks for clues

Comment: which version of boto and python is the above example ? When I try to use 2.7 Python on Boto 2.30.0; I am able to put the data to Kinesis but when I read it, I am getting XML parse error. However I am able to read the data and write the data - same data using Java SDK.

Comment: i am using python 2.7 , boto ver 2.29.1.

Comment: @EyalCh - given that this is currently the most complete example of using boto to consume Kinesis on the internet (that I can find), would it be possible to give a little more detail as to how you would implement a continuous polling function, including how one deals with new shards on a stream, running a consumer for each shard etc?

Comment: Needless to say, I've now found a pretty complete example here: https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-poster-worker! Nevertheless, thanks for the useful answer!

Comment: @EyalCh can you let me know if can get specific record from 'Data' ?

Comment: @sb0709 there is no such option today (also in boto api http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/kinesis.html). kinessis represent a stream, and you can get records only by a certain location from a stream (and not by record id).

Comment: @EyalCh Thank you!

Comment: @EyalCh - Is there any scope where we can put record in different USER,ROLE and ARN?