# Is there a Kinesis Connector for PyFlink?

Tags: python, apache-flink

I'm starting to work on a streaming application and trying to figure out if PyFlink would fit the requirements I have. I need to be able to read from a Kinesis Stream. I saw on [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/kinesis.html) that there is a Kinesis Stream Connector, but I can't figure out if that's available for the Python version as well, and, if it is, how to configure it.

*Update:*

I've found [this other doc page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/python/table-api-users-guide/python_table_api_connectors.html), that explains how to use connectors other than the default ones in Python. I've then downloaded the Kinesis jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kinesis_2.11/1.11.2). The version I've downloaded is `flink-connector-kinesis_2.11-1.11.2`, which matches the one being referenced [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/kinesis.html).

Then, I changed this line from the script in the documentation: `t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("pipeline.jars", "file://<absolute_path_to_jar>/connector.jar")`.

When trying to execute the script, however, I'm getting this Java error: `Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kinesis' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableSourceFactory' in the classpath.`.

I've also tried removing that config line from the script, and then running it as `./bin/flink run -py <my_script>.py -j ./<path_to_jar>/connector.jar`, but that got me the same error.

What I interpret from that is that the Jar that I added has not been properly recognized by Flink. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consuming a kinesis stream in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100206/consuming-a-kinesis-stream-in-python)

Comment: I don't think so, that explains how to connect to Kinesis in Python using boto or the Kinesis Client Library, but I'm interested in a Kinesis Connector for PyFlink, like the one in the link I put in the question's description, except that that one only explains how to use it in Scala and Java, but not Python.

Comment: No ,it's not explaining how to connect with boto only. If You check another answer there you will see that they also suggest using " Kinesis Client Library (KCL) for Python"

Comment: yeah, I had edited my comment. KCL doesn't answer my question, I'm looking for a PyFlink connector

Answer (score 1):

It may be relevant to clarify that PyFlink is currently (Flink 1.11) a wrapper around Flink's [Table API/SQL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/). The connector you're trying to use is a [DataStream API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/datastream_api.html) connector.

In Flink 1.12, coming out in the next few weeks, there will be a Kinesis connector for the Table API/SQL too, so you should be able to use it then. For an overview of the currently supported connectors, [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/) is the documentation page you should refer to.

**Note:** As Xingbo mentioned, PyFlink will wrap the DataStream API starting from Flink 1.12, so if you need a lower-level abstraction for more complex implementations you'll also be able to consume from Kinesis there.

Answer (score 0):

because there are many connectors to support, we need to contribute back to the community one after another. We have developed the Kinesis connector locally. Since users have demand of Kinesis connector, we will contribute it to PyFlink. Now the relevant [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/python/datastream_tutorial.html) of PyFlink datastream is still improving.You can take a look at [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18761) first to see the supported features