# Looking for an example of Pyflink with Kinesis

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-kinesis, pyflink

I have a kinesis stream to which I want to listen using pyflink.

I have installed the *Apapache-flink@1.12.2* package for python3,
I saw a few examples for using Kinesis in python (such as this one: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403036* )
and understood from the following: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018578/1322801* that this version should support connecting to Kinesis.

I wasnt able to find an example for using it, anyone knows a good tutorial for this purpose?

Thanks!